# what is the fastest way to get a dataframe from a sql view?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I dont have the rights to create a table from the view but I can read this view.
Database has no Table juste one view.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(sql='select * from my_view')`

Comment: There is no keyword argument sql

Comment: I think that's supposed to be `df = pd.read_sql('select * from my_view', conn)`

Comment: If the database had no tables, where is the data in the view coming from? A view is a pseudo table defined by a `SELECT`. The data can't exist in the view.

Comment: From another database but we dont have acces. We got one view and I have to deal with it. This is a large view and it take too much time to display it or transform it into a DataFrame

Comment: df = pd.read_sql('select * from my_view', conn)  = too much time

Comment: Then improve the performance of the `VIEW`, that seems like the problem here.

Comment: I Only can read the VIEW

Comment: Ask the people that manage your server instance / databases. There is little you can do in the query to "speed things up" without more intimate knowledge of the view, the query that defines it, the tables it uses, etc.

Comment: Clearly the problem here is the `VIEW` and or tables and they (lack of) indexing; that is what you, or someone else, needs to fix. You can't make a `SELECT *` from a `VIEW` faster without altering the view or tables it references.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple and straight forward,
Import the sql server library
And call the view with the proper connection

```
import mymssql
Import pandas as pd

import pymssql  
conn = pymssql.connect(server='yourserver.database', user='yourusername@yourserver', password='yourpassword', database='AdventureWorks')

sql_query = "SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM view"
df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn)
```